# guard-minitest runs ALL tests not just the ones for the target file changed

Tags: minitest, guard

I stripped my Guardfile down to this. If I edit a controller guard starts ALL tests.

```
guard :minitest, all_on_start: false, all_after_pass: false, spring: true do
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_controller\.rb$})  { |m| "test/controllers/#{m[1]}_controller_test.rb" }
end
```

Am I missing something here?